# Умножать на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

друзья есть `span`

```
<span id="priceSize">8.92</span>
```

как умножать например на `2` делаю так:

```
var priceSize = $('#priceSize').text();
console.log(priceSize * 2);
```

но я получаю `NaN` понятно что в `priceSize` не число, но если делать

`parseInt($('#priceSize').text());`

получаю только `8` как мне правильно умножать например на 2 чтобы вышло `17.84`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки зачем `parseInt` на дробном числе? Логично, что надо использовать `parseFloat`.

---

А еще можно писать так:

```
var priceSize = +$('#priceSize').text();
console.log(priceSize * 2);
```

или так:

```
var priceSize = $('#priceSize').text();
console.log(+priceSize * 2);
```

Это такой хак, с помощью которого строку можно привести к числу, т.к. идет попытка применить операцию сложения к строке и неявного её приведения.

Comment: ну вот все время забываю что javascript не на много отличается от php спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что `toNumber` и так вызывается:

```js
var priceSize = $('#priceSize').text();
console.log(priceSize * 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="priceSize">8.92</span>
```

Вы получаете `NaN` по какой-то другой причине, например, внутри этого `span`-a есть что-то еще.